# Generating random graphs with "esami" package

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, random, esami

I want to display graphs with random variations using the variables in the `esami` package. I have tried with tikz but when I put the `\FPsv` inside the coordinate of a point I get lots of error messages. Here is my code:

```
\FPsetpar{s0}{-4}{4}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle, grid=both,
  ymin=-5, ymax=5, ytick={-5,...,5}, ylabel=$s$,
  xmin=0, xmax=8, xtick={0,...,8}, xlabel=$t$,
  domain=0:8,samples=101, % added
]
\draw [very thick] (0,\FPsv{s0}) to (1,1) to (2,1);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Maybe I should use different packages to do this task?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please tell us where `\FPsv` comes from. It does not seem to be part of `fp`, nor of Ti*k*Z nor pgfplots. And then it would be interesting to know what `s0` is.

Comment: Hi, it is a command that you use in esami when you want to use a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a macro inside the `tikz` code, its name must not contain numbers, just letters. Moreover, it would be better to generate the calculated values outside the `tikz` code, by using the macro `\FPval` as in this example:

```
\FPsetpar{a}{2}{8}
\FPsetpar{m}{2}{8}
\FPval{c}{m*a-1}
\FPsetpar{b}{2}{\c}
\FPsetpar{ka}{1}{2}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[thick,->](-\a,0)--(4,0)node[below]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->](0,-1)--(0,3)node[right]{$y$};
\draw[dotted,thick] (2,1.5)--(2,0);
\draw[dotted,thick] (2,1.5)--(2,1.5);
\draw[fill] (2,1.5) circle (1pt);
\node at (2,-.3){\scriptsize{$\a$}};
\node at (-.3,1.5){\scriptsize{$\sempli{b}{2}$}};
\draw[dashed] (\ka,1.5) circle (2.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, at the moment the parametric version of the exercise does not work.

You can also use the `pstricks` package to work with parameters in graphics.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to use the esami package to generate a random number. The following code also gives the first coordinate a random value in the interval `[-4,4]`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle, grid=both,
  ymin=-5, ymax=5, ytick={-5,...,5}, ylabel=$s$,
  xmin=0, xmax=8, xtick={0,...,8}, xlabel=$t$,
  domain=0:8,samples=101, % added
]
\draw [very thick] (0,{8*(rand-0.5)}) to (1,1) to (2,1);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks but if I use the esami random variable I am also able tu use the random number again to generate the solutions in the multiple choice question

Comment: @MarcoDisce In that case you should provide us with a complete MWE, i.e. a document that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}`, generates these random numbers and can be compiled. Then the plot can be added. (Note also that I did not see a single example in the `esami` manual in which the variable of `\FPsetpar` has a number in it like `s0`.)